# itunes connect analytics availability?

Tags: app-store-connect, itunesconnect-analytics

When will the analytics in itunes connect they showed at WWDC be available? I thought it comes when they update the whole itunes connect, they did an update but it was still missing. Then I thought it will be available when iOS 8 is released, but no. Then I thought you have to update your app using xcode 6 but no.

So is it only me or is the analytics feature in itunes connect still not be available. and if so, when will it be available? why apple does not give any information about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It still has to come for everybody, they promised for late 2014 but they're late...

EDIT 30/04: It's finally coming!!  https://analytics.itunes.apple.com/

EDIT 01/05: Got it!!! [image]

Comment: Thanks! I am really looking forward to these numbers, much more interesting to me than other analytics like flurry and so on. Just Strange that they do not tell anything about when it will be available.

Comment: Probably they're very busy! It would be very interesting but it miss a very important thing: it would be useful to have the possibility to add some counters (for example how many times a view is displayed or a button pushed)

Comment: You can have counters to see how many times a button has been hit and many more with the usual analytic tools like flurry. Just set events, super easy to implement. But the itunes connect analytics will provide numbers only apple can provide about your app in the app store and on the users devices. so for me these numbers are much more interesting than counts of hitting buttons in my app - i have these numbers, never look at them...

Comment: Did someone have it? I'm still "anaylitcsless"

Comment: I still can't see it and we are already on Feb 7, 2015. Any news on this subject?

Comment: -.- you're right... Apple announced it for late 2014, they're clearly late but only them know when they will release it...

Comment: Let's guess it won't come out until WWDC 2015

Comment: Is strange; it looks disappeared, as they haven't never presented it! No words about this delay, no words about this feature on Apple's sites...that's not the Apple way...

Comment: @Matte.Car Actually, it's exactly the Apple way, although we're clearly off the topic here. They'll release it when they're ready (which I hope is sooner rather than later!)

Comment: Hmm. So this is the thread that shows up on google when I'm trying to find out why the hell Analytics is still not available to me.

Comment: I believe it! Apple talk about this feature for 30 seconds during xCode WWDC then silence and so,  a few of people heard about it and lot of them forget it! Even in Apple forget it!